# Advanced where clause for Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query as example:

```
select * from table where updated_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

How can I put this into ->where() for Eloquent model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you can use:

```
->where('updated_at', '>=', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))
```

as mentioned already by @user2486, but for such case I prefer this way:

```
->whereRaw('updated_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)');
```

For me it's a bit cleaner to read.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel use [DB::raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions) to use all mysql inbuilt function

```
->where('updated_at', '>=', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))
```

Comment: I see. I assume this is common practise solving advanced where problem when using Larvels' ORM?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and I have something like this:

`$query->where('item.created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subMonth(3));`